# Question about Fouriers Inversion Theorem.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

This is my professors definition of the FIT.

> **Fourier Inversion Theorem:** *Assume that $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}).$ Define the Fourier transform to be
>   $$\widehat{f}(\xi)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)e^{-iy\xi} \ dy.\tag 1$$
>   Then, as an equality in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ we have the inverse*
>   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\widehat{f}(y)e^{ixy} \ dy. \tag2$$

These notations confuse me a lot. In $(2)$, don't we actually want to get back $f(y)$ from $\widehat{f}(t)$ just like it says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)? But then Wikipedia kind of contradicts(?) itself [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem).

Can anyone explain what is going on here with the symbols? I understand it as if we start with $f(y)$ and apply the tranform, we get $f(\xi).$ So far so good. But when we apply the inverse transform, It should be applied to $\widehat{f}(\xi)$ and give us back our original $f(y)$?

Comment: One problem is that at first your integrals and functions don't have to be well-defined. The $L^2$ Fourier inversion theorem is that for $f \in L^2$ then $\lim_{A,B \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty | f(t)-f_{A,B}(t)|^2dt = 0$ where $f_{A,B}(t) =\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-B}^B e^{ity}(\int_{-A}^A e^{-ixy}f(x)dx)dy$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of variables that were used is confusing. Note the $x$ and $y$ in your second equation of

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\widehat{f}(y)e^{ixy} \ dy. \tag2$$

are basically "dummy" variables, with $x$ being a placeholder for the variable of the function $f$ and $y$ specifying the variable being integrated. As such, it's just as accurate to use

$$f(y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{iy\xi} \ d\xi. \tag3$$

instead, where I've replaced the $y$ with $\xi$ and $x$ with $y$. This shows the inverse transform does use $\widehat{f}(\xi)$ to go back to your original $f(y)$. I trust this help to explain the issue to you.